# Compare time in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to compare different times of outlets with ipad current time so what i did was this

```
if(CT!=nil && startTime!=nil &&endTime!=nil)
{

    /* If current time is greater than begin time but less than end time then he can give feedack
     */
    if (([CT compare:startTime]== NSOrderedDescending) && ([CT compare:endTime]== NSOrderedAscending) ) {

        return YES;
    }

    else if (([CT compare:startTime]== NSOrderedSame) || ([CT compare:endTime]== NSOrderedSame))
    {
         return YES;
    }
    else if (([CT compare:startTime]== NSOrderedDescending) && ([CT compare:endTime]== NSOrderedDescending))
    {
        return NO; // out of outlet timings
    }
```

This seems to be working good till now but when i change the outlet time to

start time = 18:30PM 
end time = 2:00 AM

Then in that case the above code fails, when the ipad clocks at 1:00AM then the first if condition fails so i added this code below

```
 if (([CT compare:startTime]== NSOrderedAscending) && ([CT compare:endTime]== NSOrderedAscending))
    {


    }
```

Now as a developer i am sure that if the device clocks at 1:00 AM then it wont fail but what if somebody updated the outlet timing to

start time = 9:00AM 
end time = 11:00 AM

and current device time = 8:00 AM

then in the above case my the second code will fail.

what i want is some suggestion as in what i can do in the second if condition

Code that creates CT is :

```
 NSDate *sysDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString = [df stringFromDate:sysDate];
NSDate *CT = [df dateFromString:timeString];
```

startTime and endTime are date objects stored in the plist.

Comment: Show the code that creates CT, endTime and startTime. I suspect they are NSStrings.

Comment: The very last `else if` clause is simply wrong. Drop `if` and change it to simple `else`.

Comment: ok let me try that @hamstergene

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking or trying to achieve. Can you explain what you want to do in plain english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your conditions as if there were numbers instead of dates and see what they actually do (`NSOrderedDescending` becomes `>` "greater than", `NSOrderedAscending` becomes `<` "less than"):

```
if (ctNumber > startNumber && ctNumber < endNumber)
{ ... }
else if (ctNumber == startNumber || ctNumber == endNumber)
{ ... }
else if (ctNumber > startNumber && ctNumber > endNumber)
{ ... }
```

I hope this way it's obvious the last one is not what you mean at all, and the other condition you tried later was still incorrect. The correct one is `(ctNumber < startNumber || ctNumber > endNumber)` which is exactly what standalone `else` would do, so you can just drop it:

```
if (ctNumber > startNumber && ctNumber < endNumber)
{ ... }
else if (ctNumber == startNumber || ctNumber == endNumber)
{ ... }
else 
{ /* otherwise ; everything else ; in all other cases */ ... }
```

But you really should follow @ILYA2606 advice and compare time intervals (which are numbers) in future to avoid further confusions like this. It will also allow you to use `<=` and `>=` and so drop the middle condition:

```
NSTimeInterval ctNumber = [CT timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval startNumber = [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval endNumber = [endDate timeIntervalSince1970];

BOOL ctLiesInsideInterval = (ctNumber >= startNumber && ctNumber <= endNumber);
return ctLiesInsideInterval;
```

And finally, I have to point out that the date formatter code that creates `CT` is nonsense and is equivalent to simply using current time:

```
NSDate* CT = [NSDate date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert NSString to NSDate, compare timeIntervals:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];    
NSDate *CTDate = [df dateFromString:CT];
NSDate *startDate = [df dateFromString:startTime];
NSTimeInterval CTInterval = [CTDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval startInterval = [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval deltaInterval = startInterval - CTInterval;

if(deltaInterval < 0){
    //Ascending (CT < startTime)
}
else if(deltaInterval > 0){
    //Descending (CT > startTime)
}
else{
    //Some (CT = startTime)
}
```

Comment: and what about end time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
 NSDate *currentDate=[NSDate date];  

 NSTimeInterval daysInSeconds = 60*60; 
 NSDate *starttime= [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:daysInSeconds];

 daysInSeconds = 2*60*60;
 NSDate *endtime= [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:daysInSeconds];

 if( [starttime compare:currentDate]==NSOrderedAscending ){
     //Ascending (CT < startTime)
 }

 if( [starttime compare:currentDate]==NSOrderedDescending ){
     //Descending (CT > startTime)
 }

 if( [endtime compare:currentDate]==NSOrderedAscending ){
     //Ascending (CT < endtime)
 }

 if( [endtime compare:currentDate]==NSOrderedDescending ){
     //Descending (CT > endtime)
 }
```

Comment: I want to compare both the start time and end time together which i have already done check my code above, the place where i am stuck is when the user updates time and goes into the next day so the time comparison becomes a bit tricky.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to compare start and end time with current time or else start and end time compare with each other. And also which time do you want to update either start and end time or current sys time?

Comment: i want to compare current system time with start time and end time and regarding the update, the user can update start and end time both at any given instance.

Comment: In the above code i gave static intervals means for 1hr from current time to start time  i used 60*60  and for 2hrs from current time to end time i used 2*60*60. Like that if user change 'n' hours you can give that many hours to time interval for both start and end time.